# DocumentProperties fails in XE6; works in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe6

There's another bug tucked away in Delphi XE6 (probably added around the time Unicode support was added).

You can originally expose it by trying to call:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Printer.Orientation := poLandscape; //use Vcl.Printers
end;
```

This fails with the cryptic error

> *Operation not supported on the selected printer*

### Debug their code

When you trace into the VCL, the problem comes down to the fact that the global `TPrinter` was unable to get a `DEVMODE` structure for the printer. This fails when it tries to call the Windows [`DocumentProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183576(v=vs.85).aspx) function from Vcl.Printers:

```
if DeviceMode = 0 then  // alloc new device mode block if one was not passed in
begin
    DeviceMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND,
          DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, nil, nil, 0));
    //...snip...
end;

bufferSize := DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, PDeviceMode(@dummyDevMode), PDeviceMode(@dummyDevMode), 0); //20160522 Borland forgot to check the result
```

What is strange is that `DocumentProperties` is failing: it is returning **-1**. This is strange because there's nothing particularly conceptually *wrong* with the parameters.

`DocumentProperties` isn't documented to **SetLastError** on failure, but GetLastError consistently returns:

> 50 - The request is not supported

### Code Review

There is some pretty bad code going on here:

- it's calling `DocumentProperties` and not checking the return value (*returns a value less than zero if it fails*)
- `DocumentProperties` returns a *signed* 32-bit integer
- doing underflow when `GlobalAlloc` takes an **unsigned** 32-bit integer
- `DocumentProperties` fails by returning `-1`
- that is converted into `$ffffffff` when being passed to `GlobalAlloc`, when then tries to allocate 4 GB of memory

### But it only fails in XE6

What is strange is that the same code works in Delphi 7. It shouldn't be failing in Unicode-enabled XE6. Looking at the header translation of `DocumentProperties` from `Winapi.WinSpool` in XE6:

```
function DocumentProperties( hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: LPWSTR; const pDevModeOutput: TDeviceMode;  var pDevModeInput: TDeviceMode;  fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall; overload;
function DocumentProperties( hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: LPWSTR;       pDevModeOutput: PDeviceMode;      pDevModeInput: PDeviceMode;  fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall; overload;
function DocumentPropertiesA(hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: LPSTR;  const pDevModeOutput: TDeviceModeA; var pDevModeInput: TDeviceModeA; fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall; overload;
function DocumentPropertiesA(hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: LPSTR;        pDevModeOutput: PDeviceModeA;     pDevModeInput: PDeviceModeA; fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall; overload;
function DocumentPropertiesW(hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: LPWSTR; const pDevModeOutput: TDeviceModeW; var pDevModeInput: TDeviceModeW; fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall; overload;
function DocumentPropertiesW(hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: LPWSTR;       pDevModeOutput: PDeviceModeW;     pDevModeInput: PDeviceModeW; fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall; overload;
```

They did some pretty fancy `const-var` / `typed-untyped` overloading footwork there.

Where Delphi 7 has the simpler:

```
function DocumentProperties( hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: PChar;     const pDevModeOutput: TDeviceMode;  var pDevModeInput: TDeviceMode;  fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall;
function DocumentPropertiesA(hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: PAnsiChar; const pDevModeOutput: TDeviceModeA; var pDevModeInput: TDeviceModeA; fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall;
function DocumentPropertiesW(hWnd: HWND; hPrinter: THandle; pDeviceName: PWideChar; const pDevModeOutput: TDeviceModeW; var pDevModeInput: TDeviceModeW; fMode: DWORD): Longint; stdcall;
```

### Complete Minimal Test Program

It's after midnight here. Some of you are just waking up. And i'm past my bedtime, with a lot of cursing and swearing:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Windows, WinSpool;

var
    dwBufferLen: DWORD;
    defaultPrinter: string;
    ADevice: PChar; //Pointer to printer name
    printerHandle: THandle;
    devModeSize: Integer;
    deviceMode: THandle;
begin
    dwBufferLen := 1024;
    SetLength(defaultPrinter, dwBufferLen);
    GetDefaultPrinter(PChar(defaultPrinter), @dwBufferLen);
    SetLength(defaultPrinter, dwBufferLen);
    ADevice := PChar(defaultPrinter);

    if not OpenPrinter(ADevice, {var}printerHandle, nil) then
        raise Exception.Create('Error checking removed for expository purposes');

    devModeSize := DocumentProperties(0, printerHandle, ADevice, nil, nil, 0);
    if devModeSize < 0 then
    begin
        //DocumentProperties is documented to have failed if it returns a value less than zero.
        //It's not documented to have also SetLastError; but we'll raise it anyway (Error code 50 - The request is not supported)
        RaiseLastOSError;
        Exit;
        //It's a good thing we fail. Because the return value -1 is coerced into an unsigned $FFFFFFFF.
        //Delphi then asks GlobalAlloc to try to allocate 4 GB of memory. *le sigh*
    end;

    deviceMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, NativeUInt(devModeSize));
    if deviceMode = 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('It''s DocumentProperties above that fails. GlobalAlloc is just the victim of being asked to allocate 4GB of memory.');
end.
```

How to make go?

### Bonus Chatter

- [QC#6725](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=6725): A separate printing related bug, that was closed eight years ago, that still exists in the VCL. They pass an invalid parameter to a Windows function they shouldn't even be using. The function then fails with the invalid parameter, causing the code to fall-back to using a 16-bit Windows legacy compatibility function that checks `win.ini`. All this rather than using the correct function in the first place.

Comment: Is there a question in your report? Anyway, the test program works for me in Delphi-10.1-Berlin (and XE7).

Comment: The only related thing I could find was this: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9807.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this bug too ... It always returns -1 but only if I debug in IDE.
The bug just appeared out of the blue. I think it was a Windows Update or an automated driver update. I didn't change anything specific on my Workstation setup.
Well after hours of testing and debugging, I noticed a trick which solved the problem:

Querying for "GetDriverInfos" seems to issue some kind of reset and the PrinterSystem starts working.

```
DevSize := DocumentPropertiesA(0,FDriverHandle,FDeviceName,nil, nil,0);
if DevSize = -1 then
begin
  log('Failed to communicate with printer driver! Trying to ByPass Bug ');
  GetDriverInfos(FDriverHandle);
  DevSize := DocumentPropertiesA(0,FDriverHandle,FDeviceName,nil, nil,0);
  if DevSize <> -1 then
     log('Bug bypassed.');
end;
```

I know that's strange, it worked for me (Using Berlin 10.1). We had this bug in all Delphi versions before, appearing randomly.

Comment: Okay finally i found out a little more ... GetDriverInfos .. didnt seam to work quite as expected .. the bug reappeared ... but!!!!
it seams the problem is x64 x86 related.
if i switch the test-code from (http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/de/showcode.php?id=658) from x86 to x64 it starts working (DocumentProperties returns the Correct-Value) ... if i turn back to x86 it stops working (DocumentProperties returns -1).

it looks like the x86 app tries to operate with x64 drivers that will not work.

Comment: Found an interessting resource with the same issue which seams to be bitness-related: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool.documentproperties

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post a "TL;DR" of the information of pinvoke.net

I had to replace

```
  hMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, pcName, StubDevMode, StubDevMode, 0));
```

with

```
  hMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, pcName, PDeviceMode(0), @StubDevMode, 0));
```

The full code is:

```
   FDevMode := nil;
   if OpenPrinter(pcName, FPrinterHandle, nil) then
   begin
    if hMode = 0 then  // alloc new device mode block if one was not passed in
    begin
//      hMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, pcName, StubDevMode,StubDevMode, 0));
      hMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, pcName, PDeviceMode(0), @StubDevMode, 0));
      if hMode <> 0 then
      begin
        FDevMode := GlobalLock(hMode);
        if FDevMode = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
        if DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, pcName, FDevMode^,FDevMode^, DM_OUT_BUFFER) < 0 then
        begin
          GlobalUnlock(hMode);
          GlobalFree(hMode);
          hMode := 0;
        end
      end;
    end;
   end;
```

Since the first use of `DocumentProperties()` has the only purpose to determine the size of the devmode, there is no problem with setting the out paramter to a null pointer.